# Check if front page within function passed to action

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm trying the following...

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function' );

function my_function() {
   if(is_front_page()) {
     // do something
   }
}
```

For some reason it cannot detect if it is a front page or archive, or any type of page for that matter if the function is sent to an action.

How can I check if it is front page before sending to action?

Comment: Ajax requests are sent to admin-ajax.php so is_front_page() will always return false.

Comment: You should check `referer` to know from where came the ajax request

Comment: Or just include the current page ID or whether it's the front page in the AJAX request.